# Access "calling scope" and strange behaviour

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a simple snippet of code :

```js
function SomeCtrl($scope) {
  $scope.modify = function(value) {
    $scope.something = "Hello";
  };
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app>
  <div ng-controller="SomeCtrl">
    <div ng-repeat="toto in [1,2,4,5]">
      <input ng-model="something" />
      <input ng-model="something" />
      <button ng-click="modify()">Modify</button>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Does anyone can explain how I could change it so the modify() function only change the textfields inside the scope of the button I click ?

I also don't get why only the text fields which have not been edited are modified by the function.

Thank you very much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because ng-repeat creates it's own scope. Using prototypal inheritance. By declaring ng-model you're creating a new field on that new scope.

But this will work for what you're trying to do.

```
 <div ng-repeat="toto in [1,2,4,5]" ng-init="something = {}">
      <input ng-model="something.hi" />
      <input ng-model="something.hi" />
      <button ng-click="modify(something)">Modify</button>
    </div>
  </body>

.controller('ctrl', function ($scope) {
  $scope.modify = function (something) {
    something.hi = "hello";
  }
})
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I knew about ng-init but it seems a dirty solution to me. In my snippet the "something model" is saved in the ng-repeat scope. Is there a way to access this scope without creating a new variable ? Do you have an idea why in my snippet only the "non-modified" inputs get modified by the function ?

Comment: As too why the non-modified inputs are being modified, this is because protypal inheritance each scope that is being created is being used.  What happens is that the ng-repeat create a new scope each time. ng-model='something' doesn't create the variable something right away on that scope. It will use protype look up initially to find the attribute 'something'. So once its parent's scope has 'something' attached to it, all it's children scopes - the ng repeats will use it. Once you change this, as in you write in the input box, that scope no longer will look up it's prototype chain to find it.

Comment: As to a better way or more clean. I don't know of one. That being said. I don't think I've ever needed to create a new object inside an ng-repeat before.  In my experience the object has already been created, I just need to mutate it in the ng-repeat.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. It is really instructive. You say you never had to create an object inside a ng-repeat so there must be a better way to do what I want. Maybe you can help me : I have a 2 dimensional array (a list of teams and every team has players). I have a field "new player" for each team and a button. I want to add a player according to the content of the text field in the correct team but I can't access the field from the controller (as stated in my question)

Comment: Well if you're 100% against the ng-init the other solution would be on the button pass in 'something' and the array. Have the array push the 'something' on to it. I hope that helps!

Answer (score 2):

In this case you are just pushing out on screen the same info for times, meanwhile binding everything to the same variable. You can just simply create array and bind every input line to appropriate array element. And by pressing "modify" button, pass parameter, witch array element must be changed.

```js
 function SomeCtrl($scope) {
  $scope.something = [];
      $scope.modify = function(toto) {
        $scope.something[toto] = toto;
      };
    }
```

```html
         

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
        <div ng-app>
          <div ng-controller="SomeCtrl">
            <div ng-repeat="toto in [1,2,4,5]">
              <input ng-model="something[toto]" />
              <input ng-model="something[toto]" />
              <button ng-click="modify(toto)">Modify</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        
        </div>
```

Comment: In the angular documentation ng-repeat should create it's own scope (https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat). You solution is not very clean with multiple levels of repeats don't you think so ?